# Increase height of tableview based on contentSize

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have created tableview and in tableview cell i have given another sub tableview and also able to populate data in both table view but can't give the auto increment height of tableview, I have given the constraint height also in tableview cell but its not increasing the height of sub tableview and when i'am giving the sub tableview constraint height in main tableview its giving me error So how to increase the height of sub tableview?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if tableView == tableview1{
        return fees.count
        }else{
        return descriptionFe.count
        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == tableview1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeesTableViewCell
        let getdata = fees[indexPath.row]
        cell.billno_txt.text = getdata.Billno
            let date = getdata.recivedDate
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as NSDate
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let datenew = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString as Date)
            cell.received_date_txt.text = datenew


            cell.status_txt.text = getdata.status
            cell.total_amount_txt.text = getdata.AmountPaid

            let date1 = getdata.recivedDate
            let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            let dateFromString1 : NSDate = dateFormatter1.date(from: date1)! as NSDate
            dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let datenew1 = dateFormatter1.string(from: dateFromString1 as Date)
            cell.date_txt.text = datenew1




        return cell

        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeesTableViewCell
//           

        cell.innertableviewheight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height



             cell.inner_txt1.text = fees[indexPath.row].Billno

            cell.inner_txt2.text = fees[indexPath.row].AmountPaid

            return cell
        }
    }
```

in sub tableview cell

```
class FeesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet weak var billno_txt: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var date_txt: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var total_amount_txt: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var status_txt: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var received_date_txt: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var innertableviewheight: NSLayoutConstraint!



    @IBOutlet weak var inner_txt1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var inner_txt2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var inner_tableview: UITableView!

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        innertableviewheight.constant = inner_tableview.contentSize.height

            }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
           }


}
```

here's mine UI design 
[image]

I'am confused can we increase the height of sub tableview inside of main table view cell .I need some suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

you can have array of size for each cell in which store calculated size according to content.

after that use

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    // return your sizeArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

e.g your 1 row of entry take 20 height

let suppose your 1st row have only 1 item you can store 20
your 2nd row have only 3 item you can store 60 and so on

```
let sizeArray = [20,60]();

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return sizeArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: how to give array size can you give example here

Comment: ya i got this but how it can done in mine code above i'm confused